# Resizing Video on macOS for Apple App Store Page

Tags: macos, video, video-conversion

Sorry for posting this. I'm having lots of trouble resizing a video dimension for adding to the apple app store.

The video was recorded from the simulator in 1290x2796, the app store is saying it wants 886x1920

I'm looking for a terminal command, or something to get this video resized. It looks like Photos cannot do it, iMovie is gone nowadays, does anyone know a mac friendly option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved this, here are the steps to record a video on the simulator and get it to go the the Apple App Store Page as an App Preview

STEP 1: Record the video, run the simulator and go to File > Record Screen

STEP 2: Overwrite the audio, this is to avoid the, 'corrupted audio error'

From terminal

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4
```

STEP 3: Change Dimensions of Video

Next run the output into another ffmpeg command to change the dimensions

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf scale=886:1920 -r 30 outputFinal.mp4
```

STEP 4:

Finally adding the video for some reason adds a bunch of unneeded black video. My 27 Second clip was turned into 27 Seconds plus another 4 mins of black screen.

So go into Preview, Photos, Quicktime, or whatever and trim your final product.

That's it, With those four steps you can go from recording a video on the simulator to having apple accept the video on the app store page.

Thank you for all the comments and suggestions

Comment: Good call, also if you need it to be exact you can add the setsar like so `ffmpeg -i outputipad.mp4 -vf scale=1200:1600,setsar=1 -r 30 outputipadFINAL.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -acodec copy -crf 12 -vf scale=886:1920,setsar=1:1,fps=60 output.mp4`

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=886:1920 output.mp4`

On the app store both deliver the corrupted audio error, both leave the file with this weird slowmotion thing

Comment: I tried it with a different .mov file I got from a real device, same thing, as soon as it's resized, when I open it, it has this weird slowmotion handles in Preview. I don't get it